# Increasing code coverage for nested if-elses in Python

Tags: python, if-statement, mocking, automated-tests, code-coverage

I am working on a framework that provides some values to user and they do some analysis on those values.

What is the best way to increase code coverage in automated testing?

A quite frequent use:

```
def foo(...): # A user defined method that I dont have control over

  a_long_running_function()

  value = AFrameworkObj.important_value   # I can mock this object

  if   value == AFrameworkObj.a_const_value1:   # I can mock this const value
    bar1(...)

 elif value == AFrameworkObj.a_const_value2:
    bar2(...)

  elif value == AFrameworkObj.a_const_value3:
    bar3(...)

  ...

  another_long_running_function()
```

I can run `barN` by mocking `value` and the `const` objects (either by value or via `__eq__`). Is there a way to execute other `barM` methods without re-running the whole method?

- Static code analyzers are not so helpful as users dont use type annotations much
- Not sure if is it even possible (or make sense) to execute all statements of if-else block
- Is there a kinda 'replay' option, i.e. get snap-shot after first `long-func` then re-run if-else block?

I currently have a mock class for the `important_value` return `a_const_valueN` to satisfy each if-else. However, I need to re-run the whole `foo` to exercise other if-else cases.

My main objective is to increase code coverage for automated testing.

I m using `coverage` module to get code coverage report.

Comment: Are there important side effects of `a_long_running_function` execution for your tests? If no, mock it with `a_short_running_function` while testing all `if`/`elif` parts. But why do you have something that is running for a long time in your tests? Does it process some data? If so, make the data smaller.

Comment: Just extract the `if/elif` chain into its own function and test that.

Comment: `long-func` actually takes less than a second but adds up in repeated tests, as you guys mentioned its implementation is mocked but I wonder if I can even skip that.

The code is not owned by my team, so we cannot modify it (yes, this is an ugly limitation)

Comment: Yes, if you refactor as I suggested above.